# rspec-fire specs passing when they shouldn't

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying out [rspec-fire](https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire) but it doesn't seem to behave as the README suggests. My project is here:

https://github.com/andyw8/try-rspec-fire

When I run:

```
rspec spec/user_spec.rb
```

it passes, as expected. But when I run:

```
rspec -Ilib/email_notifier.rb spec/user_spec.rb
```

it still passes, even though the README says that should fail (since `email_notifier.rb` is an empty class).

Am I misunderstanding how rspec-fire should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README was slightly wrong.  This is the command that you actually need:

```
bin/rspec -Ilib -remail_notifier.rb spec/user_spec.rb
```

The command that you ran (based on the README) was putting `lib/email_notifier.rb` onto the load path, but it was not requiring it anywhere.  The class needs to be loaded for rspec-fire to do its interface verification for you.

I've just [updated the README](https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire/commit/84eb8ca68845c3d1648b5507737e2ae3019c3328).  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I've blogged about trying rspec-fire: http://blog.andywaite.com/2013/02/21/playing-with-rspec-fire/